# Icons Centered in Chome and Firefox but not Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have 4 icons on my front page below the banner image that show up centered on Chrome and Firefox but are off center in Safari. I'm also having a browser dependency issue with the banner image call to action "Tours". It is displaying the button border on both Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

Anyone know what my issue might be here for either one of these issues?

My website is: http://foodforlifetours.com/

Code for the call to action buttons on the banner image:

```
<style>
#front-page-button-2:hover {
background-color:#0f0f0f !important;
}
</style>

<a href="http://foodforlifetours.com/tours/" id="front-page-button-2" style="background:none;  font-size:20px !important; border:1px solid white !important; text-shadow: 2px 2px black !important; color:white !important" class="button large">Tours</a>
```

Comment: What are your safari and firefox versions?

Comment: @cchacholiades safari v. is 8.0.4 and firefox is v. 36.0.4

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove these styles:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

from:

```
.vc_icon_element.vc_icon_element-outer .vc_icon_element-inner .vc_icon_element-icon
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to have any issues cross browser. Part of the issue I think you where running into was that you where using an icon font which was inheriting the text-align: center from one of the container divs. Removing the position absolute values as Leo suggests above and just inheriting text align: center seems to fix it.

Comment: awesome! That worked. Any idea what the issue is with the border not showing up around the call to action button in Firefox is?

Comment: I see the border on firefox v 36.0.4

Comment: Fixed the border issue by using outline:1px solid black; instead of border:1px solid black;